# Windows Mobile: how to hide Size property on a Custom Control

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, custom-controls

I'm developing a Windows Mobile WinForm app with C# and .Net Compact Framework 2.0 SP2.

I have a control that inhertit from System.Windows.Form.Control that I want to make private Size property. How can I do that?

I've tried this:

```
new private Size;
```

But it doesn't compile.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a public property with the same name Size in your control:

```
public Size Size
{
    get { return base.Size; }
    set { base.Size = value; }
}
```

Then you can do something in the setter to prevent your control size from being changed to a size that doesn't match your image.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
    new private Size Size
    {
        get { return Size; }
        set { Size = value; }
    }
```

However hiding the Size property isn't recommended. You basically break the contract that is expected from a Control and you may get runtime exceptions when other classes are trying to interact with it.

Comment: Maybe doing private the set part of the property can solve the problem you've exposed. My control contains an image and I want that the control has the same size of the image and none can change its size.